# How does this separation of the variable from the fraction result in $3\cdot \frac{1}{x}$ & not $\frac{3}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I wish to write the following expression as the product of a whole number or a fraction and variable expression. The answer given in my textbook is as follows:

$\frac{3}{x} = \frac{3\cdot 1}{1\cdot x} = \frac{3}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{x} = 3\cdot \frac{1}{x} $

However, I am not sure how to get to $3\cdot \frac{1}{x} $. When I complete the multiplication I get to $\frac{3}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{x} = \frac{3}{x}$, which of course loops me back round!

Comment: $3/1$ is just $3$.

Comment: I'm confused. What is the question? $\frac3x$ and $3 \frac1x$ are two ways to write the same thing.

Comment: There's no reason to downvote this question.

Comment: There's no reason to upvote this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated we have

$\frac{3}{x} = \frac{3\cdot 1}{1\cdot x} = \frac{3}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{x}$

Now we know that  $\frac{3}{1}=3$ (dividing by 1 does not change a number).

Hence, we have

$ \frac{3}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{x}=3\cdot \frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 4):

The key is simply to notice that

$$\frac31=3$$

Thus,

$$\frac31\cdot\frac1x=3\cdot\frac1x$$

Comment: Ah! This makes perfect sense. Thanks so much for spelling that out :)

Comment: @Hemmed No problem, I hope it all works out :-D

Answer (score 0):

What you learned about fractions with numerical numerator and denominator works just as well in algebra.

You are probably comfortable with 
$$
3 \times \frac{1}{7} = \frac{3}{7}\ .
$$

It's still right when you replace the $7$  by $x$ .

In general, 
$$
a \times \frac{b}{c} = \frac{a \times b}{c}\ .
$$

As a beginning student, you're pretty safe assuming 
all the straightforward rules of arithmetic carry over to algebra. A little further along in your studies you may have to think about just why the rules of arithmetic work with numbers and with variables.

Comment: Many (or most) of my college students are not comfortable (or even agree with) that first assertion.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I agree. It's part of what we have to teach them.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Once teaching number theory I asked students to factor $625 - 196$ using $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$. One said "I didn't know that algebra worked for numbers too."

Comment: http://www.madmath.com/2016/12/observed-belief-that-12-12.html